# Can I set the $remote_user to be logged in an nginx access_by_lua script?

Tags: nginx, lua

I'm doing access with lua and I'd like to log the remote user. I tried setting `ngx.var.remote_user = 'username'` but it didn't show up in the logs. How can I get my log messages to include the remote user as determined by lua?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create your own remote_user variable in ngx_lua and log that instead using ngx.log directive as it is not always that all core nginx variables can be written to by ngx_lua.

```
content_by_lua '
    [ ... ]
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "LOG FORMAT GOES HERE")
';
```

Only issue with this is that it will go into error.log and not access.log

Comment: I created my own remote_user variable e.g. `ngx.var.oidc_user` and logged it by including `$oidc_user` in `log_format`.